# Compare new elements in set with old elements in another set - Java

Tags: java, set

I have `Set` of Object which has existing values and getting a new `Set` values as an update. If the new `Set` does contain the old Object then I do nothing, if the new `Set` contains new Object then I want send create update and if the new `Set` doesn't contain an existing object then I want send a delete update.

Object has two fields :

```
  private PreferenceType preferenceType;
  private String preferenceValue;
```

Currently I am comparing the existing Set objects against new Set objects and if I don't find any existing object in new set then sending the delete update.

```
private void sendDeletePreferenceMessage(Set<AccountPreference> existingAccountPreferences, Set<AccountPreference> accountPreferencesFromRequest) {
    int counter = 0;
    for(AccountPreference accountPreference : existingAccountPreferences) {
      for(AccountPreference accountPreference1: accountPreferencesFromRequest) {
        if(accountPreference.getPreferenceType().equals(accountPreference1.getPreferenceType()) &&
                accountPreference.getPreferenceValue().equals(accountPreference1.getPreferenceValue()))
          counter++;
      }
      if(counter == 0) {
        accPrefDeleteSender.send(accountPreference);
      }
    }
  }
```

And also comparing the new set of objects against existing set of Objects to find the new updates that I want send as a create update

```
private void sendCreatePreferenceMessage(Set<AccountPreference> accountPreferencesFromRequest, Set<AccountPreference> existingAccountPreferences) {
    int counter = 0;
    for(AccountPreference accountPreference : accountPreferencesFromRequest) {
      for(AccountPreference accountPreference1: existingAccountPreferences) {
        if(accountPreference.getPreferenceType().equals(accountPreference1.getPreferenceType()) &&
                accountPreference.getPreferenceValue().equals(accountPreference1.getPreferenceValue()))
          counter++;
      }
      if(counter == 0) {
        accPrefCreateSender.send(accountPreference);
      }
    }
  }
```

This works perfectly but I believe this could be simplified in a better way. Any suggestion of doing this better!

Comment: What I can see it that you are trying to determine  if these two sets have dumplicate elements, if so why not use `contains(Object o)`  as we can finish the job within one `for` loop?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention, existing object has preferenceId which new object from the request doesn't have. So they never be equal, I just want to compare based on type and values.

Comment: Not only I am checking for duplicates but I am checking if the new set has any new objects and also does it not contain any existing one.

Comment: `compare based on type and values`, is that the way you define a `new object`? I mean if the type&value are not both the same you say it is a new one?

Comment: You can define a custom `hashcode` and `equals`method for `AccountPreference `(by overriding), ensure that two objects of `AccountPreference` with the same `type` and `value` have the same `hashcode` and `equals` with each other. Then you can use `contains` mthod of `Set`, which can save you a `for` loop.

Comment: Yes. For example 'existing type:Language and value:English', 'new type:Langauge, value: Spanish' then I consider it as a new object. 'Type' here is an 'Enum', so it is always for existing and new one.

Comment: As I said in earlier comment, Equals method may doesn't work in my case because existing object has an extra preferenceId which new object doesn't have

Comment: `existing object has preferenceId which new object from the request doesn't have. So they never be equal, I just want to compare based on type and values. ` So you can define the `equals` mehtod based on their `type` and `value`

Comment: IMHO,you employed the `Set` interface but didn't use its benifits.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two `AccountPreference` Objects: one with id field, and another without id. I don't know if it's possible without using interfaces or abstract classes. Nevertheless, according to your comments it seems to me you're confused how to override `Object.equals` method, so I'll give you an example:

```
class MyObjectWithId {

    private long id;
    private String someField;

    public String getSomeField() {
        return someField;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other){
        if (this == other) return true;
        if (other == null || !other.getClass().isInstance(MyObject.class)) return false;
        MyObject myObject = (MyObject) other;
        return this.getSomeField().equals(myObject.getSomeField());
    }
}

class MyObject {

    private String someField;

    public String getSomeField() {
        return someField;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other){
        if (this == other) return true;
        if (other == null || !other.getClass().isInstance(MyObjectWithId.class)) return false;
        MyObjectWithId myObjectWithId = (MyObjectWithId) other;
        return this.getSomeField().equals(myObjectWithId.getSomeField());
    }
}
```

As you can see, you **can** ask if the two *different* types of Object are equal (in this case, there isn't need for overriding `hashCode`).

Now you should be able to do the rest (regarding your original question about two Sets)

Comment: Sorry my comments made you confuse. Existing objects are queried from database and have an id. New objects are from request and doesn't hold an id becuase they are yet to saved in DB. Now my specific question is not related to number of for loops rather I am having two methods to find out what are new objects in request and if request is missing any existing objects. I want to combine those two methods into one to find the same.

Answer (score 0):

Set has a method `boolean contains(Object o)`.

You don't need two `for` loops, just iterate through one `Set` and check if another `Set` `contains()` the object!

You also need to override the `boolean equals(Object o)` in the POJO!

```
class MyObject {

private PreferenceType preferenceType;
private String preferenceValue;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (this == o) 
        return true;

    if (o == null || o.getClass()o.getClass() != getClass()) 
      return false;

    if(this.getPreferenceType().equals(o.getPreferenceType()) && this.getPreferenceValue().equals(o.getPreferenceValue()))
        return true;

    return false;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Object has equals and hashCode methods overidden with all the fields that I do not want to modify. My problem is not with two for loops here rather I am having two methods, one for finding new objects from the new set and one for finding if the new set has any objects missing from old set. I am trying to simplify these two methods into a single one in a better way